# insert more then form information after submit using mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have a simple form:

```
  <form action="/persons" method="POST">
    Name:<input type="text"  name="name"><br>
    URL:<input type="text"  name="quote"><br>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
```

I use mongodb to store the name and url to the database:

```
app.post('/persons', (req, res) => {
    db.collection('persons').save( req.body, (err, result) => {
        if (err) return console.log(err)
        console.log('saved to database')
        console.log(req.body)
        res.redirect('/')
    })
})
```

And now, for each url & name i want the document to contain more values (that the user does not insert), like ratio, that should be inserted into the db after the user sends "submit".

For example, given some url and the name "Jessica Alba", i want the document to contain: 
{ url: .... , name: Jessica Alba, ratio: 0 }

I tried different things and failed to succeed. what's the best option?

Comment: did you try adding req.body.ratio=0 before saving it ?

Comment: do you mean instead of req,body, {req.body, req.body.ratio = 0 } ?

Comment: I meant before calling db.collectionName.save(), add a line to add ratio property.

Comment: db.collection('persons').save({ ratio: "0", age: 19, status: "P"}), when I added that before, it didnt work...

Comment: app.post('/persons', (req, res) => {
req.body.ratio=0
db.collection('persons').save( req.body, (err, result) .....

Comment: Thank you very much. it worked.

Comment: accept the answer if it helped.

Answer (score 3):

Properties of Json objects can be accessed using dot operator.

Node file :

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var path = require('path');
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test',connectCallback);
function connectCallback(err, db) {
  col = db.collection('persons');
  console.log('Connected to mongodb');
  }

var app = express();
//middlewares
app.use(bodyParser());
//routes
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname+'/index.html');
});
app.post('/persons', (req, res) => {
    req.body.ratio=0
    col.save( req.body, (err, result) => {
        if (err) 
            return console.log(err)
        console.log(result)
        console.log('saved to database')
        console.log(req.body)
        res.redirect('/')
    })
})
setTimeout(function() {
    app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Sample app listening on port 3000!');
    });
}, 1000);
```

Index.html file:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="/persons" method="POST">
            Name:<input type="text"  name="name"><br>
            URL:<input type="text"  name="quote"><br>
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```